# Hide a div when ng-hide function is executed and set to true

Tags: angularjs

I have a div as follows

HTML

```
<div ng-hide="checkStatus()">Show only if checkstatus is false</div>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.data = 23;

$scope.checkStatus() {
   if($scope.data === undefined){
        return false;
   }
   else return true;
}
```

If i execute this, it says data is undefined. Can someone let me know how to pass this variable to the checkStatus() function. Also this 'data' variable is dynamic and can change frequently.

I want the div to keep an eye on this 'data' variable and show or hide depending on its value.

Can someone let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Change your javascript to: $scope.data = true;

$scope.checkStatus() {
 return $scope.data;
}

Comment: In the code snippet you provided `checkStatus` doesn't have proper JS syntax and invalid. Is it a copy paste error? Is it `$scope.checkStatus = function() { `maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the scope variable directly in the `ng-hide` expression:

```
<div ng-hide="data !== undefined">
   $scope.data is undefined<br>
</div>

<div ng-show="data === undefined">
   Maybe you should do something about that!!
</div>
```

The `ng-hide` and `ng-show` directives evaluates the AngularJS expression every digest cycle and shows or hides the element if the expression is truthy.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73zcuL80/).

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript to:

```
$scope.data = true;

$scope.checkStatus = function() {
 return $scope.data;
}
```

Comment: hi Shivas, can you also explain the reason. i am new to angular. why would defining a variable as $scope.data work and var data wont work

Comment: In your original code, the var data is not available inside the $scope.checkStatus() scope when you call checkStatus() from your html

Comment: Indeed, that's how closures in JS work. What's more, you don't need a function. Just assign your flag to some property in $scope object and use angular two way data binding.

Comment: @TheOpti- is there an easier way than this. i know 2 way data binding. how can we use that concept here ?

Comment: @shivas- i modified a bit. $scope.data is usually undefined and dynamically changes to a number. If it is undefined, it should return false otherwise return true. Can you let me know what should be done in this present case